# HOW to make minio mapping folder to mount point on winserver?

Tags: minio

my winserver disk
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qlHt.png

minio web
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u51n.png

I just duplicate some files to the folder，but on the webpage I didn't see them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is intentional - starting with our 2022-06-02 release, we deprecated the "Filesystem" backend for new deployments.

Moving forward, these Single Node Single Drive (SNSD) topologies instead implement our erasure coding backend using a zero-parity configuration. This means you can access our erasure-coding dependent features like versioning and object locking.

Using a single backend for all our topologies significantly increases our ability to iterate and improve the product. It should also reduce friction from users who expect that behavior not realizing they are running in "filesystem" mode.

What you can do instead is to start your SNSD deployment against an empty folder, then use the `mc.exe` utility to populate the deployment with the bucket and objects as necessary using something like `mc.exe mirror` or `mc.exe cp --recursive`.

Our docs have more detailed instructions on [Pre-Existing Data](https://docs.min.io/minio/baremetal/installation/deploy-minio-single-node-single-drive.html) for SNSD deployments.